# Using automapper for nested objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using profiles and looking for the best approach on the following, what I have in my profile is not working.

```
public EbayItemProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Item, EbayItem>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Availability.ShipToLocationAvailability.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Sku, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Sku))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Product.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
        }
```

Here are some example object setups which I am trying to map

```
var items = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item()
                {
                    Quantity = "2",
                    Sku = "Test-Sku-2",
                    Name = "Test-item-2"
                }
            };
```

to ->

```
 var expected = new List<EbayItem>()
    {
        new EbayItem()
        {
            Availability = new Availability()
            {
                ShipToLocationAvailability = new ShipToLocationAvailability()
                {
                    Quantity = "2"
                }
            },
            Sku = "Test-Sku-2",
            Product = new Product()
            {
                Title = "Test-item-2"
            }
        }};
```

Can anyone help or advise here?
.NET 6.0, Automapper 11.0.0

Comment: What is your error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.ForPath()` method. I have created a mapping profile and this should work in your use-case.

```
CreateMap<Item, EbayItem>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Availability.ShipToLocationAvailability.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Sku, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Sku))
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Product.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Comment: Perfect thank you much appreciated! :)

Comment: How would you so it if you there is a property which is IEnumerable?