# AutoMapper DTOModel with Nested List to Model

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, automapper

I have a Question.
I have 2 Dto Object and one Model.

What i'm trying todo is map the ***AssetDTO*** to the ***Asset Model*** using *Automapper*.

I have no clue on how to accomplish this.

```
    public class AssetDTO
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string CodeType { get; set; }
        public List<MetricDataDTO> Data { get; set; }            
    }

    public class MetricDataDTO
    {
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        public string Flow { get; set; }           
    }
```

I have one model that look like this.

```
 public class Asset
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string CodeType { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        public string Flow { get; set; }
           
    }
```

I tryed setting up the mapping with automapper but without any luck :(
Hope anyone can help me out,Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if suppose the value and flow inside asset is array, I think your current model for `Asset` need to be change (i.e. by creating new field `List<MetricData>` like `List<MetricDataDTO>`). Later you can check this one [AutoMapper - Mapping list of objects to bigger list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74451743/automapper-mapping-list-of-objects-to-bigger-list-of-objects).

In case for each asset there's only one value and flow, your model for `AssetDTO` will become:

```
public class AssetDTO
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string CodeType { get; set; }

    public MetricDataDTO Data { get; set; }
}
```

And for such case, here the example for nested object (based on [Using automapper for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619311/using-automapper-for-nested-objects)): https://dotnetfiddle.net/qVg59r

Below answer also much more simpler https://stackoverflow.com/a/74471904/10766263

Comment: Thanks for the example! wroks perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lucian Bargaoanu!

If you need more control when flattening, you can use IncludeMembers. You can map members of a child object to the destination object when you already have a map from the child type to the destination type.

This allows you to reuse the configuration in the existing map for the child types MetricDataDTO  when mapping the parent types AssetDTO and Asset .

It works in a similar way to mapping inheritance, but it uses composition, not inheritance.

```
cfg.CreateMap<AssetDTO, Asset>().IncludeMembers(s=>s.MetricDataDTO);
```

You can check this link for details.
https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Hope it can help you.

Comment: There is a better way, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers.

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu Thank you very much, I will update my answers.